# Finding gradient with w.r.t. matrix input(s)

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion, matrix-calculus

Suppose that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times \ell}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{\ell \times m}$ are fixed matrices and ${\bf z} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is a fixed vector. Let $V \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times k}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times d}$, and define $f(\Phi(V,W)) =  A\,\sigma_2\left(B\,V\,\sigma_1(W\,{\bf z})\right)$ with $f \colon \mathbb{R}^\ell \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\Phi \colon \mathbb{R}^{m \times k} \times \mathbb{R}^{k \times d} \to \mathbb{R}^\ell$ defined by $$f({\bf y}) = A\,\sigma_2({\bf y}) \quad \text{and} \quad \Phi(V,W) = B\,V\,\sigma_1(W\,{\bf z}),$$ respectively. Here $\sigma_2 \colon x \mapsto x^2$ is a square function applied component-wise to its argument, and $\sigma_1 \colon x \mapsto \max\{x,0\}$ denotes a component-wise application of the ReLU nonlinear function. I am stuck at the exact computation of the gradient of $$f(\Phi(V,W)) =  A\,\sigma_2\left(B\,V\,\sigma_1(W\,{\bf z})\right)$$ with respect to its (matrix) arguments $V$ and $W$, i.e., I would like to know $\nabla_V f(\Phi(V,W))$ and $\nabla_W f(\Phi(V,W))$.

---

Attempt: To derive the expression for $\nabla_V f(\Phi(V,W))$ I resort to a perturbation argument. Denote by $a \odot b$ the Hadamard product of of two matrices (or vectors) $a$ and $b$, we can write
\begin{align*}
f(\Phi(V+\Delta V,W)) &= A\,\sigma_2\left(B\,(V + \Delta V)\,\sigma_1(W\,{\bf z})\right) \\
&= A\,\left(B\,V\,\sigma_1(W\,{\bf z}) + B\,\Delta V\,\sigma_1(W\,{\bf z})\right)\odot \left(B\,V\,\sigma_1(W\,{\bf z}) + B\,\Delta V\,\sigma_1(W\,{\bf z})\right) \\
&= f(\Phi(V,W)) + 2\,A\,\left(B\,V\,\sigma_1(W\,{\bf z})\right)\odot \left(B\,\Delta V\,\sigma_1(W\,{\bf z})\right) + \mathcal{O}(\|\Delta V\|^2).
\end{align*}
However, I am not sure how to read from the previous identity about the expression of $\nabla_V f(\Phi(V,W))$. The argument needed to find $\nabla_W f(\Phi(V,W))$ seems a bit harder...

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\g{\gamma}
\def\G{\Gamma}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\r#1{\op{ReLu}\LR{#1}}
\def\s#1{\op{Step}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\p{\partial} \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$The Frobenius $(:)$ product is a concise notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
P:Q &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n P_{ij}Q_{ij}  \;=\; \trace{P^TQ} \\
Q:Q &= \|Q\|^2_F\qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\:norm} \} \\
}$$
When applied to vectors $(n=\o)$ it reduces to the standard dot product.

The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a
Frobenius product to be rearranged in many useful ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
P:Q &= Q:P \\
P:Q &= P^T:Q^T \\
S:\LR{PQ} &= \LR{SQ^T}:P &= \LR{P^TS}:Q \\
}$$
We'll also need the Heaviside Step function (aka [the derivative of the ReLu](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramp_function#Derivative) function)
$$\eqalign{
\s{\l} = \begin{cases}
\o \quad\; {\rm if}\;\;\l>0 \\
 0 \quad\; {\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
\\
}$$
and the vector variables
$$\eqalign{
x &= Wz &\qiq &dx = dW\:z \\
h &= \s{x} \\
r &= \r{x} &\qiq &dr = h\odot dx \\
y &= BVr &\qiq &dy = B\:dV\,r + BV\,dr \\
a &= A^T &&\{ {\rm a\:column\:vector} \} \\
f &= a:\LR{y\odot y} \\
}$$
It will also be useful to have a diagonal matrix for each vector variable (denoted by the corresponding uppercase letter)
to simplify Hadamard products, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
H &= \Diag{h} \qiq Hx = h\odot x \\
\\
}$$

---

Finally, we're ready to calculate the gradients of $f$
$$\eqalign{
df &= a:\LR{2y\odot dy} \\
 &= 2Ya:dy \\
 &= 2Ya:\LR{B\:dV\,r + BV\,dr} \\
 &= 2B^TYar^T:dV \;+\; 2V^TB^TYa:\c{dr} \\
 &= 2B^TYar^T:dV \;+\; 2V^TB^TYa:\c{H\,dW\,z} \\
 &= 2B^TYar^T:dV \;+\; 2HV^TB^TYaz^T:dW \\
\\
\grad fV &= 2B^TYar^T 
 \qquad\qquad \grad fW = 2HV^TB^TYaz^T \\
}$$

Comment: $f$ is a scalar-valued function thus things must simplify a lot ...

Comment: Thanks, I just assumed that $A$ was a matrix due to notational habits.

Answer (score 0):

I myself took the following approach: To obtain the expression for the adjoint operator $\nabla \Phi^*(V,W) \colon \mathbb{R}^{\ell} \to \mathbb{R}^{m \times k} \times \mathbb{R}^{k \times d}$, we let $\Delta_W \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times d}$, $\Delta_V \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times k}$, and $\Delta \in \mathbb{R}^{\ell}$. We can expand $\Phi$ as follows:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\Phi(V + \Delta_V, W) &\approx \Phi(V, W) + B\,\Delta_V\,\sigma_1(W\,{\bf z}),\\
\Phi(V, W + \Delta_W) &\approx \Phi(V, W) + B\,V\,\left(\dot{\sigma}_1(W\,{\bf z}) \odot \Delta_W\,{\bf z}\right),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $\odot$ stands for the Hadamard (entry-wise) product. Therefore, the operator $\nabla \Phi(V,W)$ is given by $$(\Delta_V, \Delta_W) \to B\,\Delta_V\,\sigma_1(W\,{\bf z}) + B\,V\,\left(\dot{\sigma}_1(W\,{\bf z}) \odot \Delta_W\,{\bf z}\right).$$
Therefore, we also have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\langle \Delta, B\,\Delta_V\,\sigma_1(W\,{\bf z}) \rangle &= \langle \Delta_V, B^T\,\Delta\,\sigma_1({\bf z}^T\,W^T) \rangle,\\
\langle \Delta, B\,V\,\left(\dot{\sigma}_1(W\,{\bf z}) \odot \Delta_W\,{\bf z}\right) \rangle &= \langle \Delta_W, \left(\dot{\sigma}_1(W\,{\bf z}) \odot V^T\,B^T\,\Delta\right){\bf z}^T\rangle.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
By the previous identity, the adjoint operator is given by
\begin{equation}\label{eq:adjoint}
\nabla \Phi^*(V,W) \colon \Delta \to \left(B^T\,\Delta\,\sigma_1({\bf z}^T\,W^T), \left(\dot{\sigma}_1(W\,{\bf z}) \odot V^T\,B^T\,\Delta\right){\bf z}^T \right).
\end{equation}
Let ${\bf y} = \Phi(V,W) = B\,V\,\sigma_1(W\,{\bf z})$, then $\nabla f({\bf y}) = \textrm{diag}(A)\,\dot{\sigma}_2({\bf y})$ where $\textrm{diag}(A) \in \mathbb{R}^{\ell \times \ell}$ represents the diagonal matrix formed by entries of $A \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times \ell}$. Thus,
\begin{equation}\label{eq:gradient}
\begin{aligned}
\nabla f(\Phi(V,W)) &= \nabla \Phi^*(V,W)\{\nabla f({\bf y})\} \\
&= \left(B^T\,\textrm{diag}(A)\,\dot{\sigma}_2({\bf y})\,\sigma_1({\bf z}^T\,W^T), \left(\dot{\sigma}_1(W\,{\bf z}) \odot V^T\,B^T\,\textrm{diag}(A)\,\dot{\sigma}_2({\bf y})\right){\bf z}^T \right).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}